# ng-show and ng-hide doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My problem probably is simple. I want hide my intro section on all pages less at home.
The problem is that when you hide hiding on every page and when you show shows on every page. I plan to just hide in the home page "/".

html:

```
<!--  Intro Section --> 
<section id="intro" class="intro-section" ng-show="home">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <a class="btn btn-default page-scroll scroll_btn floating" href="#slide">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
app.controller("employerCtrl", ["$scope", "$location", "$route", function($scope, $location, $route) {


    var path = $location.path();
    console.log(path);
    $scope.home = true;
    if(path === "/") {
        console.log("Inside");
        $scope.home = true;
    } else {
        console.log("Inside else");
        $scope.home = false;
    }


}]);
```

Comment: Utilize rootscope for this as this is globle variable, you can track it and change at every route change state.

Comment: what is the controller of home page. do hide only in home page controller

Comment: what is getting printed for those console statements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take `home` as root scope and make it `false` in `home` controller and true in `other` controllers.

```
app.controller("homecontroller", ["$scope", "$location", "$route","$rootScope", function($scope, $location, $route,$rootScope) {
        $rootScope.home = false;
}]); 

app.controller("othercontroller", ["$scope", "$location", "$route","$rootScope", function($scope, $location, $route,$rootScope) {
        $rootScope.home = true;
}]); 


<section id="intro" class="intro-section" ng-show="home">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <a class="btn btn-default page-scroll scroll_btn floating" href="#slide">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```